# How to Secure our App.Asar file while making an Exe. file of Angular project

Tags: angular, electron, exe

I just made my dummy angular project and after that i just made the cross platform application for dekstop as well as web.So after making an exe file exe will execute with app.asar file and i had made a setup for exe file with installforge application but i just saw that my all the logics all the dependencies are visible in app.asar file even after installation in client side system [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlwrN.png) So it will be issue with security i tried many approches but not able to resolve this so any one knows how can i resolve this.

Comment: This has been a problem with web based technologies...  Your sources are visible in plain text.  One option is to obfuscate your sources using something like javascript-obfuscator or similar.  But not a 100% security solution.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question. What did you actually try? Also, take a look at the ASAR [GitHub repo](https://github.com/electron/asar) -- security isn't a feature of ASAR. What are you worried about? That someone steals your code? If so, your best bet would be to obfuscate it before packaging the app, but *someone* will always be able to obtain the source code, through one way or another. That's just the tradeoff you'll need to be willing to take if you're working with Electron.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to pack your app.asar file:

1. Install asar globally using the following command

   **npm install -g asar**
2. After packing your electron app run the following command in command line

   **asar pack path_to_your_asar_file/app.asar**